# How to make a type out of a template class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, typedef, typename

Let's say I have a **template** class called **ptr**.

I can use ptr like this and it works:

```
int* data = new int(55);
ptr<int> data_ptr = ptr<int>(data);
```

But I want to use it like this:

```
int* data = new int(55);
int_ptr data_ptr(data);
```

So in short how can I label `int_ptr` to make it equal to `ptr<int>` ?

I tried typedef and typename but could not find a solution that works.

Comment: *"I tried typedef and typename but could not find a solution that works."*, what failed?

Comment: Why `typedef ptr<int> int_ptr;` would not work?

Comment: I put "template" in that line too, that must be the error. Thanks for the answers. I am somewhat new to this template concept in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using int_ptr = ptr<int>;
```

or

```
typedef ptr<int> int_ptr;
```

is what you need.